# GCE multiple nat gateways through a single outbound IP? Load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nat

We are currently using a single outbound nat server specified in the follow document by google. We would like to have more then one nat gateway to provide redundancy. They specify this in the document however each outbound nat has its own external ip address. We are running into issues with FTP and SFTP from some of our vendors with multiple external ip addresses. As a result we would like to send and receive traffic out a single IP.

Coming from the netscaler world I would ideally do this using an LB at layer 3, balancing the internal nat servers. Would this be the proper method with google cloud? Or does google even support layer 3?

Thanks,

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sending and receiving traffic out a single IP using NAT redundancy is not supported in Google Cloud using the layer 3 Load Balancer. The only way to set up multiple NAT gateways in a region and failover to each other is by using multiple IPs.